# Split array into multiple arrays in Ruby based on index

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

`array = [["Group EX (Instructor)", 0.018867924528301886], ["Personal Reasons", 0.018867924528301886]]`

and I need to split this array up, dynamically, into two arrays:

```
text_array = ["Group EX (Instructor)", "Personal Reasons"]

number_array = [0.018867924528301886,0.018867924528301886]
```

I'm currently doing this, which can't be the right way:

```
array.each do |array|
  text_array << array[0]
  number_array << array[1]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `#transpose`.

```
array = [["Group EX (Instructor)", 0.018867924528301886], ["Personal Reasons", 0.018867924528301886]]
a1, a2 = array.transpose
#=> [["Group EX (Instructor)", "Personal Reasons"],
 [0.018867924528301886, 0.018867924528301886]]
```

Repairing your existing code,

```
text_array = array.map { |x| x[0] } #give back first element of each subarray
number_array = array.map { |x| x[1] } #give back second element of each subarray
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do as below :

```
array = [["Group EX (Instructor)", 0.018867924528301886], ["Personal Reasons", 0.018867924528301886]]
text_array,number_array = array.flatten.partition{|e| e.is_a? String }
text_array # => ["Group EX (Instructor)", "Personal Reasons"]
number_array # => [0.018867924528301886, 0.018867924528301886]
```

Answer (score 0):

This too works:

```
text_array, number_array = array.first.zip(array.last)
```

but `transpose` clearly is what you want.